# Laravel Eager Loading not working, while lazy loading the same works

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, eager-loading

Currently I'm loading a relation like this:

```php
$matches = App\Match::all();
foreach($matches as $match){
    $match->thuisPouleTeam;
}
```

The reason being i need those relations loaded because it is for an api endpoint.

It works fine, but all other relation attributes are loaded via the `->with()` method for eager loading, but if I try to load this one via eager loading, it turns into an error:

```php
strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

I'm guessing this is maybe because I use the [compoships package](https://github.com/topclaudy/compoships) to allow for composite keys, so the relation method looks like this:

```php
public function thuisPouleTeam(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\PouleTeam', ["teamGuid", "pouleGuid"], ["thuisGuid", "pouleGuid"]);
}
```

But i got another relation which is practically the same:

```php
public function complementaireMatch()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Match', ["thuisGuid", "uitGuid", "pouleGuid"], ["uitGuid", "thuisGuid", "pouleGuid"]);
}
```

And this one works fine with eager loading, so I don't know what is happening really, since one works, but the other one doesn't.

Anyone has any idea what is going wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using the `Compoships` trait/model on *both* models?

Comment: That fixed it, thanks :) I missed that part in the docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `Compoships` trait/model in both models (`Match` and `PouleTeam`): [README](https://github.com/topclaudy/compoships#usage)